# Automating Infopath forms into a Servicedesk Management system (Alemba vFIre)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, automation

I'm tinkering with a script that would help automate some workplace tasks. Here is the process.

On Sharepoint a user fills out a form. The form is then emailed to their manager who approves it (Great no problems here)

Then once the form is approved our service desk get an email saying the form has been approved... This is where the un-necessary steps begin.

The SD then click on the link which takes them to sharepoint, they open up the sharepoint directory in explorer. SEARCH for the APPROVED form (as all forms are stored here including un-approved for audit purposes) then move it to a fileshare where they then need to use the Service Desk Management tool to create a "Task" upload the file tick a few boxes and then submit it.

My idea was to use a script like this:

```
import time 
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
     def on_created(self, event):
         print ("Got event for file %s" % event.src_path)

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='./Output')
observer.start()
try:
       while True:
            time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
       observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Then once an event of new file has been created (SD Has dragged file from Sharepoint to Fileshare) it Parses the XML data then auto fills in the vFire Form (I believe this is possible with the help of getting tags from Accessibility Insights for Windows)

I can elaborate more if anyone would be as so kind to even point me in the right direction!

Comment: I'd like to take you up on your offer to "elaborate more." I understand the broad strokes of what you're trying to do. What's the specific issue you're facing?